# Multiple checkboxes with select all check box in symfony form builder

Tags: symfony, checkbox, formbuilder, selectall

I need a select All check box with this multiple check boxes. If I click that select all check box, all the check boxes should be selected and deselect also I need.

```
class HabitacionFotoPrincipalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('choice', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array(
                'morning'   => 'Morning',
                'afternoon' => 'Afternoon',
                'evening'   => 'Evening',
            ),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple'  => true,
        ))
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed grammatical and improve the block code format

Comment: presuming that you don't need to actually store the information whether the user has clicked the select all box, this is easy to do with an additional checkbox + javascript/jquery directly in the view (i.e. no need to modify the actual form type class for this)

Answer (score 1):

The 'select all' checkbox is not something Symfony supports by default. So basically this would require you to add an additional checkbox, and to add Javascript logic to that.

```
$builder->add('selectAll', CheckboxType::class, array(
    'attr' => array('class'=>'selectAllCheckboxes')
);
```

And the Javascript to select all others:

```
$('.selectAllCheckboxes').click(function(){
    $('<class for other checkboxes>').click();
});
```